# How can we import products for other languages into WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, multilingual, wpml

I am using WPML, I have imported already French. I need to import English content. What are the ways?

I have checked with WPML forums, WPAllImport possibilities and WooCommerce forums. I could not find a work around to do this.